# Spring JPA multi-table relationships

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to create a product catalogue that has Product -> Attributes -> Options

So the data would look something like this:

```
product_one
  attribute_one
    option_one
    option_two
  attribute_two
    option_one
    option_two
```

The code is available on GitHub https://github.com/ccsalway/prod_info_mngr

I have created a Class for each Entity:

```
@Entity
class Product {
  @Id
  @Generatedvalue
  private Long id;
  private String name;

  // getters and setters
}

@Entity
class Attribute {
  @Id
  @Generatedvalue
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
  private Product product;

  // getters and setters
}

@Entity
class Option {
  @Id
  @Generatedvalue
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
  private Attribute attribute;

  // getters and setters
}
```

I have created a Repository for each Entity:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Product, Long> {
}

@Repository
public interface AttributeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Attribute, Long> {
}

@Repository
public interface OptionRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Option, Long> {
}
```

I have created a Service for each Entity:

```
@Service
public class ProductService {

    // Autowired Repositories

    // methods
}

@Service
public class AttributeService {

    // Autowired Repositories

    // methods
}

@Service
public class OptionService {

    // Autowired Repositories

    // methods
}
```

I have created a Controller for each Entity:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    //methods
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/product/{prod_id}/attribute")
public class AttributeController{

    @Autowired
    private AttributeService attributeService;

    //methods
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/product/{prod_id}/attribute/{attr_id}")
public class OptionController {

    @Autowired
    private OptionService optionService;

    //methods
}
```

And (finally) I have created several views for each Controller (I won't add them here).

What I am trying to do in the `product_view.jsp` View is show a list of attributes and their associated options, something like this:

```
<table id="attrTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${attributes}" var="attr">
        <tr data-id="${attr.id}">
            <td>${fn:htmlEscape(attr.name)}</td>
            <td><c:forEach items="${attr.options}" var="opt" varStatus="loop">
                ${opt.name}<c:if test="${!loop.last}">,</c:if>
            </c:forEach></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So the table would look something like this

```
product_one
  attribute_one    option_one, option_two
  attribute_two    option_one, option_two
```

The first step was to create a `@RequestMapping` in `ProductController`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String view(Model model, @PathVariable Long id) {
    Product product = productService.getProduct(id);
    List<Attribute> attributes = productService.getAttributes(product);
    model.addAttribute("product", product);
    model.addAttribute("attributes", attributes);
    return "products/product_view";
}
```

but `${attr.options}` in the View doesn't recognise the `options` key so how do I go about making this work?

I tried to add a `@OneToMany` association in the `Product` Entity but this created a table in the database with `product_id|attribute_id` which you then have to save the attribute, and then update the product with the new attribute, which also means when you select a product, you are pulling ALL attributes and ALL options which prevents Paging on those.

```
@Entity
class Product {
  @Id
  @Generatedvalue
  private Long id;
  private String name;

  @OneToMany
  List<Attribute> attributes;

 // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Do the entities even have relationships or just plain `id` and `name`?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I will add those in as I missed them.

Comment: In your controller i see `model.addAttribute("attributes", attributes);` while in your jsp `${attr.options}` is it a typo? Otherwise I guess you should use `${attributes.options}`

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Not a typo. The forEach loop takes each attribute and assigns it to attr.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

I added `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne` relationships as follows.  This method also allowed the `repository.delete(id)` method to cascade delete.

> **FetchType.LAZY** tells Spring to only fetch the underlying item(s) when requested. For example, when a request for a `Product` is made, the `id` and `name` will be fetched, but because the `attributes` are `@OneToMany` which is, by default, LAZY, the `attributes` won't be fetched from the DB until a specific call to `product.getAttributes()` is made.

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    // OneToMany is, by default, a LAZY fetch
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "product")
    private Set<Attribute> attributes = new HashSet<>();

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Attribute {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false)
    private Product product;

    // OneToMany is, by default, a LAZY fetch
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "attribute")
    private Set<Option> options = new HashSet<>();

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Option {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1, max = 32)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "attribute_id", nullable = false)
    private Attribute attribute;

    // getters and setters
}
```

In the `ProductController`, I separate the `Attributes` from the `Product` so that I can use Paging on the Attributes (whereas if I just called `product.getAttributes()`, it would fetch ALL the Attributes)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String view(Model model, @PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam(name = "page", defaultValue = "0") int page) throws ProductNotFoundException {
    Product product = productService.getProduct(id);
    model.addAttribute("product", product);
    // requesting attributes separately (as opposed to using LAZY) allows you to use paging
    Page<Attribute> attributes = productService.getAttributes(product, new PageRequest(page, 10));
    model.addAttribute("attributes", attributes);
    return "products/product_view";
}
```

Then in the view, I remember to loop over the `attributes` and not the `product.attributes` as explained above.

Because the `options` property is set to `LAZY` in the `Attribute` Entity, when the loop calls `attr.options`, Spring will make a request to the DB for the `Options` for the current `Attribute`.

```
<table id="attrTable" class="table is-hoverable is-striped is-fullwidth" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${attributes}" var="attr">
        <tr data-id="${attr.id}">
            <td>${fn:htmlEscape(attr.name)}</td>
            <td>
                <c:forEach items="${attr.options}" var="opt" varStatus="loop">
                    ${opt.name}<c:if test="${!loop.last}">,</c:if>
                </c:forEach>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```